# Setting style(color) to button in gxt/sencha

Tags: css, gwt, gxt, extjs

Hye all
I was trying the free version of **sencha API** with GWT in base and stumbled upon on the issue of setting color to a button. I tried modifying all the **CSS** get deployed in the war and tried **setting styles** also but no luck there. So kindly at least suggest a approach.Thanks in advance.

regards
la_89ondevg

Answer (score 2):

By "Sencha", I'll assume that you mean Ext GWT.

The default styling of buttons in Ext GWT comes from a sprite sheet in the resources folder that came with your download of Ext GWT. Specifically, look at `resources/images/default/button/btn.gif`. To change the colour of the button, you will have to edit this sprite sheet or create new images for the colour of button you would like to use.

If you are planning to make extensive changes to the style of widgets in Ext GWT, consider making your own theme. Themes are generally placed in `resources/themes` and can contain your own custom CSS and images. Just link your theme's style sheet in your host page and make sure your CSS rules override those in the default theme.

Answer (score 1):

maybe what you're looking for: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?97011-Change-style-for-GXT-button-component